# IHttpModule Rewritpath to Layouts folder showing 404 error

Tags: sharepoint, url-rewriting, ihttpmodule

I am working in sharepoint2010 rewrite using iHttpModule.

It works good for pages in /pages/ , /sitepages/ libraries. but when i rewrite it to a layouts folder it is throwing 404 error.

This is what i am trying to do.

http:///MyEmployees/John.aspx

I want to rewrite to http:///Employees/AllItems.aspx?ID=4

Answer (score 0):

Server.TransferRequest(..) method worked for this case. Thank you.